# Как сделать градиентную обводку символов в css? / А точнее - как сделать прозрачной внутреннюю часть символа?

Tags: css, svg, текст, градиент, оформление

Делая по макету странницу столкнулся с этим:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
это даже не обводка - а оформление шрифта (обводка отсутствует).
Задача - сделать такое в css

Comment: есть такой цвет `transparent` остальное сам)

Comment: Используйте `svg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста! Вам осталось лишь поменять цвет градиента

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/8/8b/linii-background-fon-geometriia.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#05a" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a5" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <style>
            .myStyle {
                font: 250px sans-serif;
                fill-opacity: 0;
                font-weight: bold;
                stroke-width: 12;
                stroke: url(#linear);
                dominant-baseline: middle;
                text-anchor: middle;
            }
        </style>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="myStyle">02</text>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Этот пример тоже не работает

Comment: В Firefox форма цифр кривая

Comment: немного пошаманил и вроде работает, но сьезжают другие элементы в флекс-столбе, не понимаю по какой причине, вручную передвинуть тоже не получается

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(/img/1.jpg);
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.transpText {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 10px orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="transpText">
  02
</p>
```

Comment: Тут нету градиента же

Comment: В CSS это не получится сделать , я написал для вас SVG, смотрите последний комментарий